# CSS transition applies only to first element | code works if I use console.log();

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have no clue what is going on. I am trying to apply a transition to some elements via jQuery and it only works for the first element. When debugging the code I used `console.log();` to check output and suddenly it works for all elements. I am 100% sure that the `console.log();` fixes it. I tried it already a few times and it is 100% the `console.log();`

Here is the CSS of the element:

```
#the_quiz #the_questions .question_container .answers_content .stats_elem .fill_elem {
    height: 15px;
    background: var(--my-light-max-blue);
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

Here is the JS/jQuery code:

```
$.each(all_answers, function(k, el) {
    let answer = filter_object_array(question['classic_answers'], 'id', $(this).data('answerid'));
    let stats_elem = $(this).parents('.btn_elem').find('.stats_elem');
    stats_elem.removeClass('display-none');
    stats_elem.find('p').text(answer['times_chosen']);
    let fill_percent = ((answer['times_chosen'] / total_chosen) * 100).toFixed(2);
    console.log(stats_elem.find('.fill_elem').css('width'));
    stats_elem.find('.fill_elem').css({
        WebkitTransition : 'width 1s ease-in-out',
        MozTransition    : 'width 1s ease-in-out',
        MsTransition     : 'width 1s ease-in-out',
        OTransition      : 'width 1s ease-in-out',
        transition       : 'width 1s ease-in-out'
    });
    stats_elem.find('.fill_elem').css('width', fill_percent + "%");
});
```

Everything works perfectly if I do not remove this line:

```
console.log(stats_elem.find('.fill_elem').css('width'));
```

I do not now exactly what is going on. The var is somehow consumed? If someone can explain that would be great.

The transition code is applied one by one, so there is no way it targets multiple elements.

Comment: I don't think the browser-specific styles like `WebkitTransition` are needed any more.

Comment: It's not logging itself, it's what you're logging. The parameter reads a layout value, and the layoyt is recalculated in the middle of the script execution (jQuery uses `window.getComputedStyle` under the hood when calling `css` method). This is called [layout thrashing](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/).